# Direct Messages fail with Status: 501 Payload: Null

Tags: azure-iot-hub, raspberry-pi4, azure-iot-sdk

I have a dotnet core project running version 1.37.2 of Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client on top of Linux Raspbian (Buster 5.4.83) on a RaspBerry Pi4B 2GB. The project sends telemetry every 5 mins to Azure IoT Hub. The project also registers a number of Direct Methods to be called using 'SetMethodHandler' as follows:

```
await _iotHubClient.SetMethodHandlerAsync("MethodToCall", MethodToCallHandler, null);
```

I have a number of devices out in the real world, connected to the internet over wireless LAN and standard home internet connections.

I have noticed that some devices I can call DirectMethods on relatively reliably some I have to often try three of four times before I get a successful response and others I am never able to call successfully. When the DirectMethod calls fail I always receive `{"status:501", "payload":null}`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same code\version deployed on both devices that work and don't work? 501 usually stands for "Not Implemented." In azure-iot-sdk-csharp you can read the following for 501 Error Code:

> "Equivalent to HTTP status code 501, not implemented server error. It
> is used when a method call from the service specifies a method name
> not registered with the client for callback."

**Ref:** https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/iothub/device/src/MethodResponseStatusCode.cs#L21

> some I have to often try three of four times before I get a successful response and others I am never able to call successfully.

Before you can call the methods successfully on those devices do you ever receivie a 501 error or you receive those as described [here (404 or 504)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods#response)? If never seeing 501 errors on "working devices" then you need to make sure you have same versions of the code deployed on "non-working devices".

Comment: Hi @asergaz, thanks for reaching out. It is the identical sw version deployed on identical hardware. So it seems that is not the problem. On devices that sometimes work I get the 501, payload null when it doesn't work and correct response when it does. It seems very odd.

Comment: That is interesting. And all devices use the same IoT Hub? Did you try to recreate their identity? Delete the device and add it again?

Comment: Yes, all using the same hub. No I haven't tried to recreate there identity, I will give that a go. I'm going to say that the identity is okay as I can see the devices pushing telemetry info to the hub okay.

Do you know of ways to get more debug info?

Comment: If you suspect this is server side issue, better to open an Azure Support Ticket. Engineers can look at server side logs for you: https://aka.ms/IoTHelp